# to expand or collapse rows at different sections in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on an application where i need to expand collapse rows in different sections.
Initially I tried expanding collapsing rows with a single section.
Now I want the same to happen in multiple sections.

here is my code

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
       //Return the number of sections.
       return [mysection count];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
          NSArray *rate=[mysection objectAtIndex:section];

          return [myrow count];

    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (selectedSection==indexPath.section) {


    if(selectedIndex==indexPath.row){
        selectedSection=-1;
        selectedIndex=-1;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;

    }
    //user taps on different row
    if(selectedIndex!=indexPath.row){

        NSIndexPath *prevPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:selectedSection];

        selectedSection=indexPath.section;

        selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

    selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    return;
}

else if(selectedSection!=indexPath.section){


    selectedSection=indexPath.section;


    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:selectedSection] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    if(selectedIndex==indexPath.row){
        selectedSection=-1;
        selectedIndex=-1;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;

    }
    //user taps on different row
    if(selectedIndex!=indexPath.row){

        NSIndexPath *prevPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:selectedSection];

        selectedSection=indexPath.section;

        selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }

    selectedIndex=indexPath.row;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

selectedSection=indexPath.section;

[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

NSLog(@"%d",selectedSection);
    }
```

only my rows should be expanded not my sections

Please provide with some possible solutions.

thanks in advance

my table view has multiple sections and my section has many rows

tapping on row in that section should expand

Comment: I assume you want to reload particular section when you click on particular section right?

Comment: yes i want to expand the selected row in a particular section not to expand a section

Comment: ok,can you please tell what will be the display when row click, is it a list view itself?

Comment: when row is selected it will expand and display pictures

Comment: Anyway you need to expand each section when clicked on particular section to display rows in that section.(since there are multiple section) similarly you need to it in row right?

Comment: my section is not expandable only my rows are expandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath i get the index path to a variable that can be accessed throughout the coding as below...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

in Heightforrowatindexpath

```
if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] ==NSOrderedSame)
    {
        return height;
    }
```

Comment: Protip: use `[tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];`instead of `[tableView reloadData];` to get a smooth animation